# Merge lines which has the same name ttribute and intersect in one point in QGIS

Tags: qgis, merge, intersection, attribute-joins

I have a polygon layer that has lines showing rivers. A river with the same name attribute might be consisted of a few lines touching each other. For example, in the image below, the river consists of 4 separate lines (with the same name in the name attribute column). The small line shown in red belongs to another river with a different name.

[image]

I need to merge the lines with the same names together and I know ways such as merge, join by attribute etc, however I cannot simply use merging by same name because it can happen that a line belonging to the same river (thus having the same name attribute) does not intersect with the rest of the river and cannot be merged into other lines.
Is there a way in QGIS 3.22.5 to unite the lines belonging to same river together (having same name attribute), but only those ones which touch in one point?

Dissolve window in QGIS 3.22:
[image]
Advanced window:
[image]

Comment: In other words you want to dissolve by attribute **and** location?

Comment: Yes, lines with same name who also touch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the QGIS [Dissolve](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#dissolve) tool, set the parameters this way:

- **Input layer**: your lines layer
- **Dissolve field(s)**: the river name
- **Keep disjoint features separate**: True (this is in the advanced parameters section)

[image]

Optional if you don't see the **Keep disjoint features separate** option, dissolve and then run the [Multipart to single parts](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#multipart-to-singleparts) tool.

Comment: Thanks. In the Advanced section, I do not see the option 'Keep disjoint features separate'. I see 2 options: Invalid feature filtering & Limit features processed. I am using QGIS 3.22.5-Białowieża

Comment: Thanks so much @Mayo. I added the photo of my Dissolve window to my question section since I could not add images in the comment section

Comment: As you see in the first picture, the option you mentioned is not there. The second images shows the advanced tool

Comment: ok, i think is because of the QGIS version, I thought this option was available for your version. I have QGIS 3.26.1-Buenos Aires.

Comment: I edited my answer with an option for your version.

Comment: Thanks @Mayo. I updated my QGIS version and did as you indicated. Good news is that it worked for dissolving but when I use the identify feature to select each line, they get selected separately. I want to have one united line instead.

Comment: I think the lines don't touch exactly. I test it and it worked fine for me.